# How to get Username of client system in java without using LDAP?

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, authentication

I am working on a j2ee application using eclipse with 'Tomcat Server', and in that application i **want to get username of client system** at my login page **without using "LDAP".**

i already used **System.getenv("username")** , **but it gives me the username of server system not for client system.**

then i used **"request.getRemoteUser()"** , but it **gives me "NULL" value.**
simultaneously i also try for "request.getUserPrincipal()", "request.getAuthType()".
but that also gives me 'NULL' value. and when i explored about it that why is gives me 'null' value, i found that there is no authentication level define for application.

so, as a result i put the following code in web.xml of my application :

```
<security-constraint> 

<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>demo_trial_application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
```

and after modification in web.xml (just like above), when i execute my application through URL, a dialog box opened and prompted for username and password of tomcat-user, which i declared in tomcat-users.xml .
and as a result it shows me 'tomcat' as username.

hence through the above process,i didn't get client system's username.

now, **apart from server side, i also tried javascript code to get username of client system like below code :**

```
var winNetwork=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
        alert("User Name :"+winNetwork.UserName);
```

OR

```
var winShell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        alert(winShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
```

but **the above code only run for Internet Explorer**, because i used "ActiveXObject" and it only work in internet explorer.
hence above javascript code rises browser compatibility issue.

so will you please tell me that "**how to access username of client system through Java or Javascript?**" ,but i do not want to use 'LDAP' for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A web application that you access in a browser will not have access to such information about the client machine, for security reasons.
You can stick to IE and use ActiveX, ask the user to give you the username, or have your own authentication to identify users.

Comment: if i would like to go with "LDAP" to obtain client Username then anyone please tell me How to implement it using LDAP in Java.??